# Gitlab Runner can't access Gitlab self-hosted instance

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, firewall, gitlab-ci-runner

We have a self-hosted Gitlab Enterprise installation on a Google Compute Engine instance. This instance is protected with a firewall so only our employees can access the server.

When we deploy a Kubernetes cluster (using Gitlab CI), the runners can not access GitLab and thus will not start the CI jobs.

I can manually add the the external IP-adress of the Google Kubernetes instance to our GitLab firewall (GCP Firewall allowing all protocols and ports for the selected IP ranges) and then it will work. But because we have a changing number of Kubernetes Instances (and also preemptieve instances) we have to do this manually everyday.

That is not an optimal situation. I already tried adding internal IP ranges (10.132.0.0/20, 10.0.0.0/8, 10.56.0.0/14) but that was not the solution. The runners still can't reach the gitlab server, without specifying the exact instance IP.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GKE Nodes appear as VM instances in the GCE platform. They are managed by the master node and they can be deleted (by the kube-controller) if they are deemed unhealthy. Once deleted, they are then recreated. For this reason, the IP addresses are ephemeral. It will be quite challenging to use the external IP address of each VM instance since the IP addresses change all the time. This is not a feasible solution.

One workaround would be to make good use of a [NAT Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-a-nat-gateway-with-kubernetes-engine). All outbound traffic from the GKE nodes will be routed to a specific VM instance that would act as a NAT Gateway. You would then have only 1 static IP address which is the external IP address of the [NAT Gateway](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraform-google-nat-gateway/tree/master/examples/gke-nat-gateway).

You would then have one single static IP address that you could add to the firewall rule.

Answer (score 0):

You might benefit, three years later, from [GitLab 14.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/07/22/gitlab-14-1-released/#cicd-tunnel-for-kubernetes-clusters) (July 2021)

But, only for premium and ultimate offerings, not the free version:

> ### CI/CD Tunnel for Kubernetes clusters
>
> CI/CD Tunnel for Kubernetes clusters
>
> Until now, connecting Kubernetes clusters to GitLab CI/CD required users to open up their clusters towards GitLab.
> **Some organizations do not encourage opening up their firewall externally due to security concerns**.
>
> GitLab now ships with a CI/CD Tunnel that connects GitLab Runners with your Kubernetes cluster using the [GitLab Kubernetes Agent](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/). This enables versatile GitOps workflows where the deployment logic can be coded in the pipeline.
>
> You and your team can safely use your preferred tool to run the deployment itself using `kubectl`, `helm`, `kpt`, `tanka`, or anything else without security concerns.
>
> To use the tunnel, define the `kubecontext` in your CI/CD pipeline to connect with your agent. To simplify this process, we plan to [automatically inject the `kubecontext`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/324275) into the CI/CD environment in a future iteration.
>
> The CI/CD tunnel is currently supported only from the project where the agent was configured but we are working on [adding group-level support](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/5784). You can safely start using the tunnel on GitLab SaaS and self-managed instances.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/ci_cd_tunnel.html) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/5781).

---

And [GitLab 14.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/11/22/gitlab-14-5-released/#fine-grained-permissions-control-with-the-cicd-tunnel) (November 2021)

> ### Fine grained permissions control with the CI/CD tunnel
>
> Keeping your clusters’ access safe is paramount for most companies. The CI/CD Tunnel for the GitLab Kubernetes Agent enables secure access to the cluster from within GitLab CI/CD.
>
> **Until now, the Tunnel inherited all the permissions of the service account of the installed agent in the cluster**.
> Many users need stricter permission controls, preferably at the user or job level.
>
> In GitLab 14.5, we are pleased to release a generic access impersonation and a CI/CD job impersonation. These impersonations can be specified in the Agent configuration file, and the impersonated account permissions can be managed using Kubernetes RBAC rules.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_5/configure-ci-tunnel-with-ci-job-impersonation.png -- Fine grained permissions control with the CI/CD tunnel]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/repository.html#use-impersonation-to-restrict-project-and-group-access) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/5783).