# self-hosted gitlab-runner cannot registered self-hosted gitlab on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine, gitlab-ci-runner

- gitlab version 13.8.1-ee (install with helm)
- GKE version : 1.16.15-gke.6000

I install gitlab & gitlab-runner on GKE, private cluster.

Also, I have nginx-ingress-controller for firewall rule, following docs.
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/blob/70f31743e1ff37bb00298cd6d0b69a0e8e035c33/charts/nginx/index.md

```
nginx-ingress:
  controller:
    scope:
      enabled: true
      namespace: default
    service:
      loadBalancerSourceRanges:
        ["IP","ADDRESSES"]
```

With this setting, gitlab-runner pod has error

> couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab.my-domain.com/api/v4/runners: Post https://gitlab.my-domain.com/api/v4/runners: dial tcp [my-domain's-IP]: i/o timeout

Issue is same as this one.
[Gitlab Runner can't access Gitlab self-hosted instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51038988/gitlab-runner-cant-access-gitlab-self-hosted-instance)

But I already set cloudNAT & cloud Route, also adding IP address of CloudNAT in `loadBalancerSourceRanges` in gitlab's value.yaml.

To check if cloudNAT worked or not, I tried to exec pod and check IP

> $ kubectl exec -it gitlab-gitlab-runner-xxxxxxxx  /bin/sh
> wget -qO- httpbin.org/ip

and it showed IP address of CloudNAT.
So, the request must be called using CloudNAT IP as source IP.

> https://gitlab.my-domain.com/api/v4/runners

What can I do to solve it ?

Comment: How did you deployed ingress? Did you use `stable/nginx-ingress` ? Did you follow any tutorial/guide?

Comment: @pjoterS I deployed nginx-ingress following gitlab https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/blob/70f31743e1ff37bb00298cd6d0b69a0e8e035c33/charts/nginx/index.md

Comment: `Stable` repository was deprecated few months ago. Could you try to use newest [nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm) `ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx`?
`helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx` to add repository, `helm repo update` to update it and `helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx` to deploy newest nginx.

Comment: Situation is almost same even if I use `https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx`. Using helm install and set `controller.service.loadBalancerSourceRanges: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32","yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/32"]` (1 is IP of CloudNAT). but  still got timeout error. If I didn't set `loadBalancerSourceRanges` when installing nginx-ingres, and later changing firewall rule , IP range from **0.0.0.0/0** (default) to **xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32,yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/32**, it worked. 
Somehow, loadBalancerSourceRanges may affect not only FW rule but somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It worked when I added kubernetes-pod-inner-ipaddress in loadBalancerSourceRanges. Both stable/nginx, https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx worked.

gitlab-runner called `https://my-domain/api/v4/runners` . I thought it would go through public network, so added only CloudNAT IP, but maybe it was not.

Still, it's a little bit weird.
First time I set 0.0.0.0/0 in loadBalancerSourceRanges, then added only CloudNAT IP in FW,  `https://my-domain/api/v4/runners` worked.

So, `loadBalancerSourceRanges` may be used in 2 places, 1 is FW rule which we can see on GCP, the other is hidden.